# DB Cursor FETCH NEXT woks but FETCH FIRST does not

Tags: sql, sql-server

Because of some complex work, I'm resorting to using a DB cursor. I also have to traverse through the qualifying records in a table from beginning to end more than one time. When I reach last record in the table, I'd reset the cursor to the beginning of the table again for the next pass through.

However, `FETCH NEXT` works fine, if I try `FETCH FIRST`, I get an error: `@@FETCH_STATUS = -1`. What's wrong with my cursor?

```
FETCH FIRST db_cursor INTO @VendorId, @VendorCount
```

verses

```
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @VendorId, @VendorCount
```

Using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? You need to use the SCROLL option to use FIRST.

Comment: Looks like I have a  FORWARD_ONLY cursor.  This reference shows a SCROLL option.      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

SCROLL works great

```
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR 
    SCROLL
    FOR
    SELECT VendorId, VendorCount
    FROM #venderData t
    WHERE PageIndex IS NULL
    ORDER BY VendorCount DESC;
```